# Call to a member function bind_param() on bool

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET ? = ? WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $obj->{'property'}, $obj->{'value'}, $id);
```

It says "**Fatal error**:  Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean"

**$obj->{'property'}** and **$obj->{'value'}** are strings. **$id** is int.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error says that `$stmt` is a bool, you're likely looking in the wrong place

Comment: @Rizier123 the duplicate you linked to has nothing to do with the question, it really should be closed ("can you debug my code" kind of question)/

Comment: @BenoitGarret Oh for sure it has to do something with this question! OP tries to bind a column name. Now from the dupe: `Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.` I think this has something to do with the question here

Comment: I see your point, just thought the duplicate could be really confusing without additional comments. @darxysaq the `$db->prepare` statement most likely returns false because you're trying to bind a column name, hence the duplicate, you're looking for the error in the wrong place.